# Regex: Searching several possible groups

Tags: python, regex, regex-group, information-extraction

Regex experts please help! I have the following two examples:

```
'(JEN) This is a sentence.'
'This is another sentence (412).'
```

I am trying to extract the different possible elements of these two sentences in the following way (knowing that there are three possible element types):

```
['JEN', 'This is a sentence', None]
[None, 'This is another sentence', 412]
```

Does anybody know how to solve this?

I tried the following regex:

```
r'(\(([A-Z]{3})\))?\s*([\w- ]+)?\s*(\(([0-9]{3})\))?'
r'(?:\(([A-Z]{3})\)\s*)(?:([\w- ]+))(?:\(([0-9]{3})\))' # Passive Groups
```

And for both I get errors for Invalid regular expressions.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sre_constants.error: bad character range` occurs because `[\w- ]` is interpreted as a range. It's possible to use `[\w -]`, but generally `-` should be escaped inside character classes: `[\w\- ]`.

Also, your expressions are not equivalent (aside from grouping). I'm not sure whether that was intentional, but note that the non-capturing version of `(regex)?` is `(?:regex)?`, not `(?:regex)`. In order to behave akin to the first expression, the second one should be:

```
r'(?:\(([A-Z]{3})\))?\s*([\w\- ]+)?\s*(?:\(([0-9]{3})\))?'
```

Comment: `[\w- ]` is invalid in Python, Ruby, ..., but it is valid in PCRE (matches word, `-` and space). (There is nothing wrong with your explanation, though). And "unnamed" is a bit off on the terminology, should be non-capturing group.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. +1 for the PCRE mention; I wasn't aware that would be valid.

Comment: Yes, both my attempts were intentionally different. I tried your suggestion and it too returned an error. I am using http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/python/index.html for my testing.

Comment: I just tried it with another site (http://www.pythonregex.com/) and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd say just capture the actual parentheses inside your groups, you know the resulting captures of groups 1 and 3 will have them, so you can accommodate, and the regex is certainly saner.

Also, a 'sentence' in this context is perhaps better defined as 'anything but a right parentheses'.  That being said, this works for all your inputs:

```
r'(\([A-Z]{3}\))?\s*([^(]+)(\(\d{3}\))?'
```